# How to store element permanently in echcache

Tags: ehcache

I am using **ehcahce** for caching. how do i store elements permanently in **ehcache**.

```
CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager.getInstance();
```

cacheManager.addCache("test");
cache = cacheManager.getCache("test");

Comment: Please provide more context to your question. Also please clarify what you mean when associating "caching" and "permanently".

Comment: i meant persistance on disk. i have done that thanks anyway dear